# AngularJS: decorating $http

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a simple controller, like:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    ...
    $http.post(url).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
         });
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

Everything works as expected, but I have a problem. The returning JSON is commented with /** */ for security reasons. With jQuery I have extended the $.ajax object to remove this comments  and then parse the result. I would like to achieve the same with AngularJS and somehow tell $http to remove the comments from each response too. I want to do this for my whole application and avoid typing always the same.

Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to want to transform all your `$http` responses.  I haven't done this before, but the relevant documentation is below.

> **Transforming Requests and Responses**
>
> Both requests and responses can be transformed using transform
>   functions. By default, Angular applies these transformations:
>
> **Request transformations:**
>
> - if the data property of the request config object contains an object,
>     serialize it into JSON format.
>
> **Response transformations:**
>
> - if XSRF prefix is detected, strip it (see Security Considerations
>     section below)
> - if json response is detected, deserialize it using a
>     JSON parser
>
> To override these transformation locally, specify
>   transform functions as transformRequest and/or transformResponse
>   properties of the config object. To globally override the default
>   transforms, override the $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest and
>   $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse properties of the
>   $httpProvider.

Read more in the [`$http` service documentation.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Comment: Sorry for accepting late. I actually missed an important part in the docs you mentioned (I read them before I asked). Anyway now I made an interceptor which transforms my requests thanks to your hint.

Comment: @Christian can you post your transform as an example?

Answer (score 3):

You may wish to switch from wrapping your JSON responses in `/** */` to that which is already supported out of the box by `$http`. Instead, prefix your JSON responses with `)]}',\n`.

e.g. If your JSON response is:

```
['one','two']
```

then, instead of returning:

```
/**['one','two']*/
```

simply return:

```
)]}',
['one','two']
```

For details, see the *JSON Vulnerability Protection* section in [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

Comment: Thank you. I actually saw that already. Unfortunately I cannot change it so easily because I need to remain backward compatible. This would require a lot of attention I currently do not have. I will spare this out for a later time. Anyway, I upvoted it, because other should see your answer is a really good one.